# Headless chromedp wait until download finishes

Tags: go, google-chrome-headless, chromedp

I'm using chromedp to navigate thru the website, to download PDF files which are generated by the system. It takes a while, to generate them so... Code looks like that:

```
        chromedp.Navigate("https://website.com/with/report/to/download"),
        // wait for download link
        chromedp.WaitReady("a.downloadLink"),
        chromedp.Click("a.downloadLink"),
        // wait some time to pull the file
        chromedp.Sleep(time.Minute),
        chromedp.Click("#close-button"),
```

Right now I'm waiting a minute, and then close the browser, but I don't like it that way. If there is any way to control or get some kind of "event" when file download is finished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question was asked a long time ago, but since nobody answered and the entire `chromedp` tag bunch of questions is kind of thin with answers... here goes.

You should not depend on the passage of time for any asynchronous operations.  See the `chromedp` [file download example](https://github.com/chromedp/examples/blob/master/download_file/main.go) for the correct way to download
a file. Note how they [synchronize on download end](https://github.com/chromedp/examples/blob/master/download_file/main.go#L43).